# Aggregation in Column level display

Tags: sql, oracle

Table 1

```
S_no Name Attempt Score Status 
1     sam    1      25    Fail
2     sam    2      45    Pass
3     sam    3       12   Fail
4     Dante   1      56   Pass
5     Dante   2      78   Pass
6     jill    1      16   Fail
7     Jack    1       90  Pass
```

In the Above table . number of student passed  = 2 and number od student Failed = 2.

status of the Final Attempt is taken in to Consideration .

I want to Show

```
Id Passed_no failed_no 
1    2         2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN s.status = 'Pass' THEN 1 END) as Passed_no,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.status = 'Fail' THEN 1 END) as Failed_no
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.name ORDER BY t.attempt DESC) as rnk
    FROM YourTable t) s
WHERE s.rnk = 1
```

Comment: anyother way other than rnk ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason? @EswarVignesh

Comment: Just Curious to know ..Instead using a RANK Function and Filter ...is there any other way..?

Comment: Yes, but without window functions there will be an additional select from this table, less efficient. It can be done with `exists` or a `join`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT to get the result:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT NAME ,CASE SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS='Pass' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
                      WHEN  0 THEN 'PASS' 
                      ELSE 'FAIL' 
                   END STATUS
      FROM TABLE_NAME
      GROUP BY NAME)
PIVOT (COUNT(NAME) FOR STATUS IN ('PASS' AS "Passed_no" ,'FAIL' AS "Failed_no"));
```